# Render mode doesn't work as expected

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I'm still quite new to blender so this might be an easy fix but I'm really not sure. My problem is that I would like to see how the base colors I apply to my objects look like, so I switched to render mode.
As you can see in the video, some weird stuff is going on while rendering the image, I can't even really describe what's happening there ':)
I read about wrong camera settings and wrong camera focus already, but I don't even use "Depth of field". At the end of the video I show my camera settings as well. The light source is the standard point light on 1000W.

Even if my camera or light settings are set wrong, this shouldn't explain the mess with the partly visible objects, right?

Would be cool if somebody could help :)
thanks in advance!

[youtube link to video](https://youtu.be/iS8nDMZwdho)

PS: I'm sorry that it's a youtube video, but I think it's important to see the whole video and not only images or parts :)

Comment: it's probably the last AMD driver, try to switch to the previous one, or try Properties > Render > Performance > High Quality Normals

Comment: @moonboots I think I'm blind, can't find the "Properties" tab :c Did you mean the Preferences tab under "Edit"?

Comment: https://zupimages.net/up/21/02/gsbc.jpg

Comment: @moonboots there we go! That worked for me, thanks a lot!!